# Andengine Live wallpaper : Loosing textures on low end device

Tags: andengine, live-wallpaper

I am developing a live wallpaper using Andengine GLES2 Anchor centre branch ,based on the Development Cookbook.Wallpaper works fine on mid range to high end devices but shows problem on low end devices.I have tested it on Samsung galaxy ace , Micromax Funbook tablet and the issue generator Samsung galaxy Y. Issue found only on Samsung galaxy Y the only low end device I have.

Issue

I got loosing textures of all sprites when unlocking screens sometimes,or when returning to homepage some times,Error is not generated in a predictable manner, some times it doesn't cause any issue at all, But when it occurs to make my work even in my preview mode I have to force close the application and start the app again.

These are the details of my live wallpaper,
Wallpaper have A background sprite,A main image sprite ,two BatchedSpriteParticleSystem with some initializers and modifiers
I have a sepretae folder in asset for lower end device (320*480) where I keep small images and load all images to a single texture atlas in that case other wise I am using two texture atlas one for background image,and one for my main image and the two particle images.I am using a resource manager calss as per the andengine cookbook to load textures

Please help me to sort out the issue,I dont know where iam going wrong on this 
here is my code ...

LiveWallpaperExtensionService given below

**LiveWallpaperExtensionService**

```
@TargetApi(13)
public class LiveWallpaperExtensionService extends BaseLiveWallpaperService {

    public Sprite bg_Sprite;
    public Sprite main_image_sprite;
    public SpriteBackground background;

    public BatchedSpriteParticleSystem beamParticleSystem;
    public BatchedSpriteParticleSystem starParticleSystem;

    private Camera mCamera;
    private Scene mScene;


    @Override
    public org.andengine.engine.Engine onCreateEngine(
            final EngineOptions pEngineOptions) {
        return new FixedStepEngine(pEngineOptions, 50);
    }

    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {

        Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE))
                .getDefaultDisplay();
        Utils.setGlobalWidthandHeight(Utils.getDisplaySize(display));

        mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, Global.Width, Global.Height);

        EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true,
                ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_SENSOR, new FillResolutionPolicy(),
                mCamera);

        engineOptions.getRenderOptions().setDithering(true);
        return engineOptions;
    }


    public void onCreateResources(
            OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback) {

        System.out.println("On create resourses");
        ResourceManager.getInstance().loadBlueTextures(mEngine, this);
        pOnCreateResourcesCallback.onCreateResourcesFinished();

    }

    public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback) {
        System.out.println("On create scene");
        mScene = new Scene();
        pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(mScene);
    }

    public void onPopulateScene(Scene arg0,
            OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback) {

        System.out.println("on populate ");

        final float positionX = Global.Width * 0.5f;
        final float positionY = Global.Height * 0.5f;


        bg_Sprite = new Sprite(positionX, positionY,
                ResourceManager.getInstance().mBackgroundTextureRegion,
                this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

        main_image_sprite = new Sprite(positionX, positionY,
                ResourceManager.getInstance().mJesusTextureRegion,
                this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

        /*
         * Define the center point of the particle system spawn location
         */
        final int bparticleSpawnCenterX = (int) (Global.Width * 0.5f);
        final int bparticleSpawnCenterY = (int) ((Global.Height * 0.5f) + ((Global.Height * 0.5f)) * 0.5f) - 25;
        /* Define the radius of the circle for the particle emitter */
        final float particleEmitterRadius = 50;
        /* Create the particle emitter */
        CircleOutlineParticleEmitter bparticleEmitter = new CircleOutlineParticleEmitter(
                bparticleSpawnCenterX, bparticleSpawnCenterY,
                particleEmitterRadius);

        beamParticleSystem = new BatchedSpriteParticleSystem(bparticleEmitter,
                10, 15, 50, ResourceManager.getInstance().mBeamTextureRegion,
                mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

        beamParticleSystem
                .addParticleInitializer(new ExpireParticleInitializer<UncoloredSprite>(
                        3));

        beamParticleSystem
                .addParticleInitializer(new AccelerationParticleInitializer<UncoloredSprite>(
                        -150, 150, -150, 150));

        RectangleParticleEmitter particleEmitter = new RectangleParticleEmitter(
                ((int) (Global.Width * 0.5f)), ((int) (Global.Height * 0.5f)),
                Global.Width, Global.Height);

        // Create a batched particle system for efficiency
        starParticleSystem = new BatchedSpriteParticleSystem(particleEmitter,
                1, 2, 20, ResourceManager.getInstance().mStarTextureRegion,
                mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

        /* Add an acceleration initializer to the particle system */

        starParticleSystem
                .addParticleInitializer(new ExpireParticleInitializer<UncoloredSprite>(
                        10));

        starParticleSystem
                .addParticleInitializer(new RotationParticleInitializer<UncoloredSprite>(
                        0, 160));

        /* Define min/max values for the particle's scale */

        starParticleSystem
                .addParticleInitializer(new ScaleParticleInitializer<UncoloredSprite>(
                        0.3f, 1.5f));

        /* Define the alpha modifier's properties */

        starParticleSystem
                .addParticleModifier(new AlphaParticleModifier<UncoloredSprite>(
                        0, 2, 0, 1));

        /* Define the rotation modifier's properties */

        starParticleSystem
                .addParticleModifier(new RotationParticleModifier<UncoloredSprite>(
                        1, 9, 0, 180));

        // Add alpha ('fade out') modifier
        starParticleSystem
                .addParticleModifier(new AlphaParticleModifier<UncoloredSprite>(
                        8, 10, 1, 0));




        /*
         * Create the SpriteBackground object, specifying the color values &
         * Sprite object to display
         */

        final float red = 0.7f;
        final float green = 0.78f;
        final float blue = 0.85f;
        final float alpha = 1;

        background = new SpriteBackground(red, green, blue, bg_Sprite);
        mScene.setBackground(background);
        mScene.setBackgroundEnabled(true);

        // Attach our particle system to the scene
        mScene.attachChild(starParticleSystem);
        mScene.attachChild(beamParticleSystem);

        mScene.attachChild(main_image_sprite);

        bg_Sprite.setIgnoreUpdate(true);
        main_image_sprite.setIgnoreUpdate(true);

        pOnPopulateSceneCallback.onPopulateSceneFinished();
    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized void onPause() {
        System.out.println("On paused");
        super.onPause();

        if (starParticleSystem != null) {
            starParticleSystem.setParticlesSpawnEnabled(false);
        }
        if (beamParticleSystem != null) {
            beamParticleSystem.setParticlesSpawnEnabled(false);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized void onResume() {

        System.out.println("On resume");
        super.onResume();

        if (starParticleSystem != null) {
            starParticleSystem.setParticlesSpawnEnabled(true);
        }
        if (beamParticleSystem != null) {
            beamParticleSystem.setParticlesSpawnEnabled(true);
        }

    }


    }



}
```

Please help me to sort out this issue ,I welcomes all ideas Suggestions, Any thing any thoughts of you to solve this issue ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed that Galaxy Y has lots of issues, been getting lots of crash reports for a game of mine till I blocked them from downloading it and all reports stopped [it was the only device with issues]

I suggest you do the same

edit:
if you want to chose which devices to support, you can use this example

```
<supports-screens
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:smallScreens="false"
android:anyDensity="true" />
```

modify that as you see fit

Comment: Thank you sir, I am also was think about it,Sir I like to know what's the best way to block all low end devices,In same time support mid-end and high-end devices with small screen size(320*480) devices.Or do there is any list of  low-end devices available  thus we can block them directly in play store

Comment: try defining your supported screens, I edited my answer to include that